# How to get the plot frame in Coreplot

Tags: core-plot

I want to get the plot frame of a plot (the orange region in image below),

[image: plot frame]

However, `graph.plotAreaFrame.frame` seems to be returning a NSRect of the purple area in the image (i.e. the frame of the CPTGraphHostingView in the window coordinates). No matter what I try I can't seem to get access to the frame rect which corresponds to the orange rectangle.

I want to mix some custom drawing inside the orange rectangle with plot data. For the custom drawing I and wish to draw directly in the layer coordinate system rather than converting to plot points. Do to this I have subclassed CPTScatterPlot. I know I could use annotation layers but this didn't seem to have the flexibility that I needed.

Best wishes,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orange area is called the "plot area". You can get a reference to it using `graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea`.

Comment: Should it be as simple as graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.frame to return an NSRect of the rectangle?

Comment: Yes, but use the bounds to get the drawing coordinate system inside the plot area layer.